# What is the best way to create conditional stylesheets with Sass and Symfony2's Assetic?

Tags: css, symfony, sass, stylesheet, compass-sass

My project framework is Symfony 2.0. I'm using the Compass filter via Assetic to compile my Sass files. However I'm unsure of how to structure my compiled CSS files once I place it in the head as I have conditional code to load certain css files. On top of this I want to be able to include my IE conditionals.

```
(i.e.<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->).
```

Not sure if I should be using the same If statements I have created below or if there's a more elegant solution to this:

i.e. 
CssBundle/Resources/views/stylesheets.html.twig

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% if isEspanol %}
        {% stylesheets filters=”compass” @cssBundle/Resources/css/core/es/main.desktop.scss” %}
    {% else %}
        {% stylesheets filters=”compass” @cssBundle/Resources/css/core/main.desktop.scss” %}
    {% endif %} 
<link rel=”stylesheet” href=”{{ asset_url }}” />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

CoreBundle/Resources/views/Layout/default.desktop.html.twig

```
<head>
    {% include “::stylesheets.html.twig” %}
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about symphony framework, 
but if your only problem is conditional stylesheets for IE hacks, then the answer might be **not to use conditional stylesheets**

use html conditional classes instead

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

see [Paul Irish's recommendations here](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

Comment: I suppose I could add the HTML conditional classes in the <head> within my stylesheet blocks. However I was hoping for an elegant solution since I am using Assetic to manage the stylesheets for me I thought there would be programmatic solution for adding conditionals and its relative stylesheet.